# Kernel Module insert error

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cross-compiling, kernel-module, debug-symbols

I was trying to insert an unknown module.
which in turn throws error saying, `module can not be inserted`

seems it found an `unknown symbol`.

I have a better access to whole source tree.

need clues, how can I start debugging over it.
In fact, I have never done with any module debugging.

Thanks.

Comment: It's trying to find a symbol (function or variable) which is not present in the running kernel. The module you are trying to load is making a call to a function or referencing a symbol which is not present in the kernel. Please tell us what module you are trying to load and what symbol is not getting resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Your module's dependencies are probably not being met. It seems it needs a symbol which isn't available in your currently running kernel.

Check that the symbol it needs is in your `System.map` file for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `insmod`, you should use `modprobe`, which automatically loads module dependencies.